# How we can register IOptions<AppSettings> in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

We are working in .NET Core and create a simple injector in another assembly. Here is our simple injector method:

```c#
public static void Bootstrap(Container container, IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies = null, bool verifyContainer = true)
{
    container.Register<ISUPCoreApiClient>(() => new SUPCoreApiClient("localhost"));

    if (verifyContainer)
    {
        container.Verify();
    }
}
```

Here is our `ConfigureServices` method in the .NET Core application:

```c#
 services.AddOptions();
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(options => Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Bind(options));
```

But when we use this in our controller we have got the following error message:

```c#
SimpleInjector.ActivationException: The constructor of type AuthorizeController contains the parameter with name 'appSettings' and type IOptions<AppSettings> that is not registered. Please ensure IOptions<AppSettings> is registered, or change the constructor of AuthorizeController.
```

Comment: Where does `Container` come from?

Comment: we have fixed this issue with add following line in the InitializeContainer method:                                  container.CrossWire<IOptions<AppSettings>>(app);

Answer (score -1):

Hope this works,

```
services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
services.AddScoped(cfg => cfg.GetService<IOptionsSnapshot<AppSettings>>().Value);
```

Comment: The first one is what you probably want.